# Java - How to find for a value of a variable inside an object which belongs to an Array of objects?

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to ask how do we find the element in an array with the value of a variable inside the element? Is it possible? If so, please do tell. Suppose we have an object called Pt:

```
public class Pt {
    private int x, y;

    public void setCoords(int i, int j){
        x = i;
        y = j;
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }

}
```

Then we create an Array of Pt object and also initialize it's elements.

```
Pt[] point;
point[0].setCoords(0,0);
point[1].setCoords(1,1);
```

The problem that I am having now is how do I find the element with the coordinates (1,1)?

Comment: that is easy solvable. give yourself a try.

Comment: I just realized it now. I should just simply loop at them and use the getX and getY methods right?

Comment: that is one possibility yes...

Comment: Logically it is very simple. Simply loop over values and check. You can have other solutions as well.

Comment: @StefanBeike thanks for the encouragement. I was just overthinking. My bad.

Comment: A better option would maybe to override your hashcode and equals methods in your point class and use those?

Comment: So now that you know you can do it, you could ask yourself how you might do it efficiently. (And the answer, as always, is "it depends".)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to loop through the array and check each of the elements. To loop through the array, you can use an enhanced for loop.

```
for (Pt pt : point) {
    if(pt.getX() == 1 && pt.getY() == 1){
        //what you want to do with the object...
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pt[] point = new Pt[2];
        Pt pt1 = new Pt();
        pt1.setCoords(0, 0);
        Pt pt2 = new Pt();
        pt2.setCoords(1, 1);
        point[0] = pt1;
        point[1] = pt2;

        getElement(point, 1, 1); // returns element with coords of (1, 1) or null if doesn't exist

    }

    public static Pt getElement(Pt[] point, int xCoord, int yCoord) {
        for (int i = 0; i < point.length; i++) {
            if (point[i].getX() == xCoord && point[i].getY() == yCoord) {
                return point[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You're not using the parameters `xCoord` and `yCoord`.

Comment: @Flown - oops! Correction made.